# React+JavaScript How to create an object in React with all the given fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following Sign-up page and I console log each time in the function called 'sign' once the Sign Up button is clicked. While each field is individually visible in the console, I need to make them appear as one object. Any help is appreciated, here is my code for the react function SignUp:

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  let sign = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstName); 
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={sign}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
```

Comment: Check `React.useReducer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useReducer` to create a state object of your component like this:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

const initialState = {
 firstName: '',
 email: '',
 password: '',
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_FIRSTNAME':
   return { ...state, firstName: action.payload }
  case 'SET_EMAIL':
   return { ...state, email: action.payload }
  case 'SET_PASSWORD':
   return { ...state, password: action.payload }
  default:
   return state
 }
}

export default function SignUp() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  let sign = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(state); 
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(event) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_FIRSTNAME', payload: event.target.value })}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={(event) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_EMAIL', payload: event.target.value })}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
               onChange={(event) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_PASSWORD', payload: event.target.value })}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={sign}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
console.log({ firstName , email , password });
```